# Failed to log in Firebase has not been initialized properly, please do so using the Initialize Firebase flow function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, appgyver

**Issue:**

1. I was getting below error while launching the application.

[image: appGyvery]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

1. After creating Android app in Firebase and setting up in the appGyver connector issue was resolved.

[image: firebase]